# Sticky header block module?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks

I am searching for a way to make a block behave as a drupal-highlighted area, similar to the header [here](http://demo.drupalizing.com/?theme=corporateclean). In other words, stick to the header and move along as the user roles down.

I was wondering if there is either a module that can do that, to sort of wrap the block's content or a custom workaround in my module.

I know that there exist some themes which can do that, but I would like to implement a theme-free solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just a CSS thing!  <del>There a tutorial [here](http://davidchambersdesign.com/css-fixed-position-headers/) on how to achieve it,</del> but you're pretty much just looking at some CSS like the following.

*Edit:* The tutorial has now gone, but the CSS contained is very similar to that shown below, and a quick search in your favourite search engine will return similar results.

```
#BLOCKID {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 160px;
}
```

Just apply the CSS to your chosen block and you're off.

Comment: In case someone wants to achieve the same as me, I only extented slightly by adding to my custom css this : `html, body, #page{ margin-top:70px; top: 70px; }` which moves the rest of the page downward! Thanks Chapabu!

Comment: keep in mind that every mobile browser implements position:fixed in a different manner.

Comment: Not just mobile browsers.  Some desktop browsers react differently as well.

Comment: Hello. Your tutorial link is out of date.

Comment: @Mołot Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://drupal.org/project/floating_block. It works fine and it's easy to use.

> The Floating block module allows you to keep html blocks, selected using jquery selectors in a fixed position on the page as you scroll. It works in a similar way the table header fixer in Drupal Core. This means that when the user scrolls their browser selected parts of the page can stay in the users view.